# PHP: creating a for loop with dynamic Variables

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to slim down the code:

I want to make a for loop out of this part, but it wouldn't work.

```
$line1 = $frage1[0] . '|' . $frage1[1] . '|' . $frage1[2] . '|' . $frage1[3];
$line2 = $frage2[0] . '|' . $frage2[1] . '|' . $frage2[2] . '|' . $frage2[3];
$line3 = $frage3[0] . '|' . $frage3[1] . '|' . $frage3[2] . '|' . $frage3[3];
$line4 = $frage4[0] . '|' . $frage4[1] . '|' . $frage4[2] . '|' . $frage4[3];
$line5 = $frage5[0] . '|' . $frage5[1] . '|' . $frage5[2] . '|' . $frage5[3];
```

This is my attempt:

```
for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++){
        ${line.$i} = ${frage.$i}[0] . '|' . ${frage.$i}[1] . '|' . ${frage.$i}[2] . '|' . ${frage.$i}[3];
    }
```

EDIT:
This is the solution that works (just so simple :-p):

```
for ($i=1; $i<18; $i++){
        ${"line".$i} = implode("|", ${"frage".$i});
        fwrite($antworten, ${"line".$i});
    }
```

Comment: what your expected result

Comment: it should be work. what error you have?

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant line - assumed 'line' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Beispiel_Umfrage\functions.php on line 235

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++){
        $line[$i] = $frage[0] . '|' . $frage[1] . '|' . $frage$i[2] . '|' . $frage$i[3];
    }
```

This will insert the same thing you posted abov e in line 1 to 6. Is this what you are looking for?!

Comment: OP did not want array

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++){
    ${"line$i"} = ${"frage$i"}[0] . '|' . ${"frage$i"}[1] . '|' . ${"frage$i"}[2] . '|' . ${"frage$i"}[3];
}
```

That works too!

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

You might find the documentation on [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) useful but it looks like the problem is that PHP cannot handle the unquoted string inside your curly brackets.

So instead of `${frage.$i}` you need `${"frage$i"}`.

### Another Approach

However, this is probably not the clearest way to solve this problem. It certainly gives me a bit of a headache trying to work out what this code is trying to do. Instead I would recommend adding all of your `$frage` to an array first and then looping as follows:

```
$lines = array();
$frages = array($frage1, $frage2, $frage3, $frage4, $frage5)

foreach($frages as $frage) {
  $lines[] = join('|', $frage);
}
```

Note in particular that you can use `join` to concatenate each `$frage` with a `|` inbetween each, rather than doing this concatenation manually. You could always use `[array_slice][2]` if you really did only want the first 4 elements of the array to be joined.

If you have a significant number of `$frage` variables and don't want to add them to an array manually then:

```
$frages = array();

for($i = 1; $i < x; $i++) {
  $frages[] = ${"frage$i"}
}
```

If you really need each `$line` variable rather than an array of lines, then you can use `extract` although this will give you variables like `$line_1` rather than `$line1`:

```
extract($lines, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "line")
```

However, I would recommend taking a serious look at why you have these numbered `$frage` being generated and why you need these numbered `$line` as your output. I would be very surprised if your code could not be re-factored to just use arrays instead, which would make your code much simpler, less surprising and easier to maintain.

Comment: now I have got it: the correct syntax is: ${"frage".$i}. But you were right about the quotation inside the brackets